# How to remove def and incorporate the function into the code?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to remove def function since we are not allowed to use that, but I don't know how to.

```
def is_one_away(first: str, other: str) -> bool:
    
    # check lengths
    if len(first) != len(other):
        return False
    
    error_count = 0
    for i in range(len(first)):
        if first[i] != other[i]:
            error_count += 1
            if error_count > 1:
                return False
    
    return True
```

That's the def function, but I'm trying to incorporate it into my actual code.

This is the part of the code that Im trying to incorporate it into.

```
if is_one_away(x, y):
    similarity = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the returned value to the value you're assigning to `similarity`.

Use `break` to end the loop instead of `return`.

```
if len(x) != len(y):
    similarity = False
else:
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] != y[i]:
            similarity = False
    else:
        similarity = True
```

There's no need for `error_count`, since you always return as soon as you find a non-match.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without the zip function, only basic python is allowed.

Comment: I changed it back to the way you use `range()`. But why is `range(len(x))` more basic than `zip(x, y)`?